# Validating required_with and additional rules

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I need to setup a validation rule for two date fields **arrivalFrom** and **arrivalTo**. The fields are optional, but if one of the fields are present the other is required, and should follow a specific format.

```
// Validation.
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'amount'      => 'required|numeric',
    'arrivalFrom' => 'required_with:arrivalTo|date_format:dd/mm/yy|before:arrivalTo',
    'arrivalTo'   => 'required_with:arrivalFrom|date_format:dd/mm/yy|before:arrivalFrom',
]);
```

The validation works if the only rule set is "required_with" but as soon as *date_format* or *before* is set, the *required_with* is ignored.

```
Validation Message
Please not that neither of the fields "arrivalFrom" / "arrivalTo" are set.
    The arrival from does not match the format dd/mm/yy.
    The arrival from must be a date before arrival to. 
    The arrival to does not match the format dd/mm/yy.
    The arrival to must be a date before arrival to.
```

Is there a way to achieve these validation in one go, instead of checking if the input is present and then set validation rules.

I'm using Laravel 5.4.

**EDIT : Solution**

```
// Validation.
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'amount' => 'required|numeric',
    'arrivalFrom' => 'required_with:arrivalTo|nullable|date_format:d/m/y|before:arrivalTo',
    'arrivalTo' => 'required_with:arrivalFrom|nullable|date_format:d/m/y|after:arrivalFrom',
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue myself, I added the rule **nullable** which worked as a charm. So if the field is not null, the other validation rules overrule.

```
// Validation.
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'amount' => 'required|numeric',
    'arrivalFrom' => 'required_with:arrivalTo|nullable|date_format:d/m/y|before:arrivalTo',
    'arrivalTo' => 'required_with:arrivalFrom|nullable|date_format:d/m/y|after:arrivalFrom',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Validation.
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'amount'      => 'required|numeric',
    'arrivalFrom' => 'required_if:arrivalTo,"!="," "|required_with:arrivalTo|date_format:dd/mm/yy|before:arrivalTo',
    'arrivalTo'   => 'required_if:arrivalFrom,"!="," "|required_with:arrivalFrom|date_format:dd/mm/yy|before:arrivalFrom',
]);
```

I am not sure about this. As I have never used `required_if` and `required_with` together but you can give it a try? Not sure if it will solve your problem or not.Let me know if it does.

Comment: I'll give it a shot

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work, but i fixed it otherwise.

Comment: No issue. Please share your code here so it can help someone in future. @MichaelKampmannRasmussen